# Electron,Typescript - rest arguments in function does not work

Tags: typescript, electron

I was rewriting a solution from this reply https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-582606806 to TypeScript and I don't know how to solve this TS error. I want to pass 2nd and all rest arguments to the function using spread operator but it doesn't work.
Why am I getting this error? How should I properly solve it? 
I don't have a lot of experience in TS/JS.

```
function callIpcRenderer(method: string, channel: any, ...args: any[]) {
  if (typeof channel !== 'string' || !channel.startsWith('APP_')) {
    throw 'Error: IPC channel name not allowed';
  }
  if ('send' === method) {
    return ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args);
  }
  if ('invoke' === method) {
    return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args);
  }
  if ('on' === method) {
    const listener = args[0];
    if (!listener) throw 'Listener must be provided';

    // Wrap the given listener in a new function to avoid exposing
    // the `event` arg to our renderer.
    const wrappedListener = (_event: any, ...a: any[]) => listener(...a);
    ipcRenderer.on(channel, wrappedListener);

    // The returned function must not return anything (and NOT
    // return the value from `removeListener()`) to avoid exposing ipcRenderer.
    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, wrappedListener);
    };
  }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myIpcRenderer', {
  invoke: (...args: any) => callIpcRenderer('invoke', ...args),
  send: (...args: any) => callIpcRenderer('send', ...args),
  on: (...args: any) => callIpcRenderer('on', ...args),
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are spreading `args`, and there is no constraint `args` consists of at least 1 element, TS is correctly warning you, i.e. `invoke();` would be allowed by your typings but is wrong for `callIpcRenderer` definition.

Just declare `invoke`, `send` and `on` with forced `channel` argument:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myIpcRenderer', {
  invoke: (channel: any, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer('invoke', channel, ...args),
  send: (channel: any, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer('send', channel, ...args),
  on: (channel: any, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer('on', channel, ...args),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`callIpcRenderer` expects at least 2 arguments, but you're only definitively passing 1. What happens if `...args` is an empty array in your `invoke` call? All you'd have passed is the method.
There are 2 ways to approach it. I'd recommend simply being explicit with the channel argument:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myIpcRenderer', {
    invoke: (channel: string, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer('invoke', channel, ...args),
    send: (channel: string, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer('send', channel, ...args),
    on: (channel: string, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer('on', channel, ...args),
});
```

When using a rest parameter, the type is always an array. So prefer to use `any[]` over `any`. With that in mind, you could approach it by just being more specific with the array type:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myIpcRenderer', {
    invoke: (...args: [string, ...any[]]) => callIpcRenderer('invoke', ...args),
    send: (...args: [string, ...any[]]) => callIpcRenderer('send', ...args),
    on: (...args: [string, ...any[]]) => callIpcRenderer('on', ...args),
});
```

Here we're saying that `...args` is an array that has at least one string (channel) followed by whatever else.

In regards to the first part of your code, you can also be more specific with your types. You're throwing an error if `channel` isn't a string, so why not explicitly type it to be a string? With `method`, you're checking if it's one of 3 strings, so you can use a type union to limit it:

```js
type IpcRendererMethod = 'send' | 'invoke' | 'on';

function callIpcRenderer(method: IpcRendererMethod, channel: string, ...args: any[]) {
    if (!channel.startsWith('APP_')) {
        throw 'Error: IPC channel name not allowed';
    }
    // ...
}
```

One additional option is to make the method an enum. With a larger application, it makes it easier to edit code in the future if you ever change the string value (you could do the same with channel if you have the full list at compile time):

```js
enum IpcRendererMethod {
    Send = "send",
    Invoke = "invoke",
    On = "on"
}

function callIpcRenderer(method: IpcRendererMethod, channel: string, ...args: any[]) {
    if (!channel.startsWith('APP_')) {
        throw 'Error: IPC channel name not allowed';
    }
    if (IpcRendererMethod.Send === method) {
        return ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args);
    }
    if (IpcRendererMethod.Invoke === method) {
        return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args);
    }
    if (IpcRendererMethod.On === method) {
        // ...
    }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myIpcRenderer', {
    invoke: (channel: string, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer(IpcRendererMethod.Invoke, channel, ...args),
    send: (channel: string, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer(IpcRendererMethod.Send, channel, ...args),
    on: (channel: string, ...args: any[]) => callIpcRenderer(IpcRendererMethod.On, channel, ...args),
});
```

Comment: wow that's what I was looking for entire evening ;) thank You a lot for explaining it. Now it makes sense. My code is still just a tinkering with electron but I will definitely follow your hints and make it cleaner and more scallable :)